# Setting up network with media converters not working as expected

Tags: networking, home-networking, connection, fiber

I am working on running 1Gbps internet from my house to a small building on my property about 200 to 250ft away. Here is what I'm trying to set up:

1. Run Cat5e from modem/router about 75ft to Fiber media converter
2. Run fiber optic cable from media converter to building 200 to 250 ft from house
3. Fiber optic cable plugs into media converter at destination building
4. Cat5e cable from media converter to router/switch at destination building

The problem I'm having is, when I test and connect a laptop directly to Cat5e running from destination media converter, I get <90Mbps of a 1Gbps connection.  When I plug Cat5e into destination router and connect laptop to destination router it goes down even further to <30 Gbps.

I've tested the Cat5e from the modem/router in the house on the same laptop where the Cat5e plugs into the first media converter and get >950Mbps.  All the appropriate lights seem to be lit up on both media converters.  I've attached a picture of one of them.

The media converters and fiber are brand new, just opened from the packaging.  Only thing I've done is put the fiber in some protective sheathing to run underground.

Any help?  What am I missing?  Why am I losing so much speed going through the media converters and fiber?  Also including specs for fiber and media converters below.

---

**Media Converters**: Bidi Gigabit Multi-Mode Fiber Ethernet Media Converter with 2PCS Bidi SFP LC Dual Transceiver Module Included, 10/100/1000Base-Tx to 1000Base-SX SMF RJ45 to SFP Slot up to 550M

**Fiber Optic Cable**: 100 Meters Uniboot LC to LC Outdoor Armored Fiber Patch Cable, Low Friction Single Mode Duplex Fiber Optic Cable Jumper Optical Patch Cord, 9/125um

- Connector Type   LC to LC (Uniboot Connectors)
- Polish Type  UPC to UPC
- Fiber Mode   OS2 9/125μm
- Fiber Count  Duplex
- Fiber Grade  G.657.A2 (Compatible with G.652.D)
- Jacket Color Black
- Cable Diameter   3.0mm
- Cable Jacket LSZH with low-friction characteristic
- Min. Bend Radius (Fiber Core)    7.5mm
- Min. Bend Radius (Fiber Cable)   20/10D (Dynamic/Static)
- Fiber Cords Structure    Armored, Stainless Steel Tube
- Tensile Load 200/600N (Long/Short Term)
- Insertion Loss   ≤0.15dB
- Return Loss  ≥55dB
- Operating Temperature    -20~75°C
- Storage Temperature  -20~75°C

[image: Media Converter]

Comment: My first thought is that perhaps you may be getting confused between bits per second and bytes per second.  90Mbytes-per-second is about 900Mbits-per-second, not far from 1Gbps.

Comment: Using speedtest.net, my "DOWNLOAD Mbps (copied from the website)" is 950Mbps when connected directly to the Modem/router and less than 90Mbps when connected to the converter after traversing the fiber.  Not confusing anything.  I work in the industry and know/understand the difference.  It is significantly slower.

Comment: What kind of SFP modules were included with the media converters? What link speed do the Ethernet ports (on your switches or your router or your laptop) negotiate when connected to the media converters, on the 'copper' side of the connection? Can you measure TCP retransmissions during the speed test?